# How to run e2e tests on angular-seed?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I've cloned the angular-seed repository and now attempting to run the e2e test suites.

Using the command:

npm run protractor

I get the error:

```
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.169:38366/wd/hub
Segmentation fault

npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 139
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
```

My protractor-conf.js looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 1000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

I've updated web-driver with the command "npm run update-webdriver". OS Linux mint x64

Comment: Have you run `webdriver-manager update` then `webdriver-manager-start`?

Comment: The project's frontpage is a very good starting point: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
npm install, npm start, npm run update-webdriver, npm run protractor are the main steps.

Comment: Still does not work for at least several people after following the steps.  Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100346/angularjs-trying-to-run-protractor